# NPM dependency Error while building iOS app on Expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I'm getting this error when I try to build my iOS mobile app on Expo. I've seen dependency errors before while developing my app, but I always use --legacy-peer-deps to avoid them. Is there a way to do that in this case? If not, what should I do? Here is what I saw when I looked at the logs inside of expo dev. Please let me know what I can do.

````
[stderr] 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[stderr] 
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
[stderr] 
npm
[stderr] 
ERR!
[stderr] 
Found: react@18.0.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   react@"18.0.0" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @ant-design/cssinjs@1.6.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
node_modules/@ant-design/cssinjs
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     @ant-design/cssinjs@"^1.5.6" from antd@5.3.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     node_modules/antd
[stderr] 
npm ERR!       antd@"^5.3.0" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   73 more (@ant-design/icons, @ant-design/react-slick, ...)
[stderr] 
npm ERR! 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[stderr] 
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.12.1" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR! 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.12.1" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[stderr] 
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[stderr] 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[stderr] 
npm ERR! 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! See /Users/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     /Users/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-04-19T00_02_50_805Z-debug-0.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1```
````